# Preventing VS code debug view from opening

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Seems like a simple thing but I could not find a source on the web for it and the view settings does not seem to change this behavior, while debugging every 'continue', 'step-in' or 'step-over' action makes the debug view to reopen which makes debugging very annoying, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found the right setting in the Debug section that lets you determine when to open the debug view:
[image]